# Doubt about Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When we use Rolle's theorem successfuly, it is because the function in the analysed interval $[a, b]$ is continuous, differentiable in $(a, b)$ and $f(a)$ = $f(b)$. I am asked to prove that $x^3-3x+b=0$ has exactly and only a single root in $[-1, 1]$ using only Rolle's theorem. I beg you to excuse me, because I know the answer is duplicated, but I am (maybe) too stupid to understand it. It is impossible to use Rolle's theorem because $f(-1)\neq f(1)$ for every $b\in\mathbb{R}$, so we must use intermediate value theorem. However, I can't see any relation between the fact that there is a $f'(c)=\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$ in $(a, b)$ and the roots of $f(x)$. For the second time, please, please please, you are welcome to close my question for being duplicated (better say cuatriplicated) and excuse me for annoying purposely, but at least have mercy and explain it to me.

Comment: What is $b$?  If $b$ is arbitrary, then this is false.  Are you asked to show it has _at most one_ root or _exactly one_ root?

Comment: Exactly one. And yes, $b$ is arbitray. The question asks to prove that whatever the value of $b$ is.

Comment: Then it's not necessarily true.  There's no way to prove it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If you change it to _at most one root_ in $[-1,1]$, then Rolle's theorem applies because $\frac{d}{dx}[x^3-3x+b] = 0$ at $x=\pm 1$, so the derivative exists but is never zero inside $(-1,1)$.

Comment: So it means that the function is monotone, then it can only have at most a single root?

Comment: @NicolásCastellanos Only if it is *strictly* monotone.

Comment: The way the Rolle theorem is used is the following: if $x_1<x_2$ are roots of $f(x)$ then $f(x_1)=f(x_2),$ and now you can apply the theorem. So if you make sure that $f'$ does not vanish there can be at most two roots in the interval. The IVM us applied to make sure that $f$ hasat least one root.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. $x=\pm1$ are the roots of $f'(x)$, then the Rolle's theorem says that there is $c\in(-1, 1)$, such that $f''(c)=0$. I understood how that solves the problem. What I don't understand, is how we know that $f'(x)$ won't have any root in $(-1, 1)$ besides the graph of both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

Comment: You missed the point.  If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0,$ then $f'(x_3)=0$ for some $-1<x_3<1.$ However $f'(x)=3(x-1)(x+1)<0,$ for $-1<x<1,$ a contradiction.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, I realized that doing $f'(x)=0$, we get that the derivative is only zero in $\pm1$.

Comment: Well in fact I didn't realize, it is just what @BrianMoehring said. I think this is solved. Sorry, I am maybe just burntout.